# Why do variables not work with TOP command?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

1. Why does below SQL script throw errors?
2. Is this issue with `TOP` command?
3. Or is it because of the `SELECT` statement which does not support SQL variables?

My code:

```
DECLARE @cnt INTEGER = 0;
Declare @cnt_total INT;

SET @cnt_total = 5

WHILE (@cnt < @cnt_total)
BEGIN
    SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;

    SELECT TOP @cnt * 
    FROM FOCUSCDR.PATIENTDXHISTORY
END;
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 9
>   Incorrect syntax near '@cnt'.

While above works when used.

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM FOCUSCDR.PATIENTDXHISTORY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the syntax requires parentheses:

```
DECLARE @cnt INTEGER = 0;
Declare @cnt_total int ;

Set @cnt_total = 5

WHILE (@cnt < @cnt_total)
BEGIN
   SET @cnt = @cnt + 1;
   Select  top (@cnt) * from FOCUSCDR.PATIENTDXHISTORY
END;
```

Edit:

As mentioned in the comment by @Tim Biegeleisen, you should be using ORDER BY, otherwise it makes no sense using TOP since the order will not be guaranteed and you might get non consistent results. Check out [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sqlyse-with-pankaj-manek/2015/07/31/executing-select-query-using-top-without-order-by/) for more info on it.

Comment: You should also mention that the OP should always use an `ORDER BY` clause with `TOP`.  Otherwise, using `TOP` doesn't make much sense..

Comment: Thanks! Edited :)

Comment: Thanks Rigerta !! :)